# Amending the output by adding extra value in SQL

Tags: sql, presto

I want to amending the output from SQL table for instance adding extra text or element from the selective table in SQL. And below query is not able to execute as facing mismatch input.

```
select date, '123' & text from database123

Normal Output
| Date         | Text  |
| --------     | ------|
| 01/01/2021   | Car   |
| 01/02/2021   | Car   |

Expecting Output
| Date         | Text     |
| --------     | ------   |
| 01/01/2021   | 123Car   |
| 01/02/2021   | 123Car   |
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`concat`](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/string.html#concat) or `||`:

```sql
SELECT concat('123', text), '123' || text
FROM database123
```

Comment: Hey thank you for the reply, what if add ' symbol in the concat for example ''' look like the command cannot be resolved.